# altering a stored procedure to include results from another stored procedure/query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this stored procedure which returns a list of clients details given the params

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[vExport_GetClientDetailsBySchemeAndTeam]
            @startdate DATETIME = null,
            @enddate DATETIME = NULL,
            @scheme INT,
            @teamID INT
 AS
/*returns a  list of current client details between two dates */


SELECT 
    Forename,
    Surname,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Town,
    County,
    Postcode,
    [Status],
    Telephone,
    EmergencyTelephone
    --exec vExport_GetClientDetailsBySchemeAndTeam '2010-04-06 12:00:00', '2011-04-06 12:00:00', '3', '152'
FROM
    vClients
WHERE
    vClients.ClientID in
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            E.ClientID 
            FROM vEvents E
            INNER JOIN vClients C on E.ClientID = C.ClientID
            WHERE E.EventDate between @startdate and @enddate
            --AND C.Status = 0
            AND e.SchemeID=@scheme
            AND e.TeamID = @teamID)
```

However I now need to include in the select (last eventdate) the result of another SP. which essentially looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from vEvents  E where E.ClientID =  @ClientID
order by e.EventDate desc
```

How can I return this last event date for all clients in the first select statement using the second query?

Stuck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[vExport_GetClientDetailsBySchemeAndTeam]
            @startdate DATETIME = null,
            @enddate DATETIME = NULL,
            @scheme INT,
            @teamID INT
 AS
/*returns a  list of current client details between two dates */


SELECT 
    Forename,
    Surname,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Town,
    County,
    Postcode,
    [Status],
    Telephone,
    EmergencyTelephone,
    (SELECT top 1 e.EventDate from vEvents  E where E.ClientID =  vClients.ClientID order by e.EventDate desc)
    --exec vExport_GetClientDetailsBySchemeAndTeam '2010-04-06 12:00:00', '2011-04-06 12:00:00', '3', '152'
FROM
    vClients
WHERE
    vClients.ClientID in
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            E.ClientID 
            FROM vEvents E
            INNER JOIN vClients C on E.ClientID = C.ClientID
            WHERE E.EventDate between @startdate and @enddate
            --AND C.Status = 0
            AND e.SchemeID=@scheme
            AND e.TeamID = @teamID)
```

Comment: This is not "include in the select the result of another SP", this is "include in the select the same query of another SP". I understand the result is ok for Oded nevertheless it is not the same thing.

Comment: @Skrol29 amun1000 didn't ask to use SP in the query specifically. amun1000 just wanted to include the result (last eventdate) of the SP whose query was given. I would have done it differently if SP has to be used.

Comment: @Eric.K.Yung: if it's so then the question is trivial and totaly useless. Copying a code to have it working elsewhere is trival and often a bad practice.

Comment: @Skrol29 that may be true that the answer is useless for a lot of people. However for amun1000, it's good enough - minimal code to get the job done. I used the author's code to help him get AN answer he wanted. I believe that's how one can learn better when having someone make a simple modification. I don't intend to use the code for myself.

Comment: You can further optimize your query by replacing the subquery in the `WHERE ... IN...` with a derived table that includes only the most recent EventDate in the given date range

Answer (score 0):

This is your friend:

```
create table #sp_output
(
  col_1 ... ,
  ...
  col_n ... ,
)

INSERT #sp_output EXECUTE <your-stored-procedure-of-choice>
```

The caveat is that the stored procedure **must** return a single result set, and, the table schema must match that result set exactly. So if the called stored procedure gets changed, your stored procedure is broken until the table definition is updated to match.

Answer (score 0):

Combine it down to a join against a derived table:

```
SELECT 
    Forename,
    Surname,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Town,
    County,
    Postcode,
    [Status],
    Telephone,
    EmergencyTelephone,
    E.MostRecentEventDate
FROM
    vClients C INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ClientID,
            MAX(EventDate) AS [MostRecentEventDate]
        FROM vEvents
        WHERE EventDate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
            AND SchemeID=@scheme
            AND TeamID = @teamID
        GROUP BY ClientID
    ) E ON C.ClientID = E.ClientID
```

Using a temp table for something this simple would be unnecessary and a complete waste of database resources.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

1. use Table Functions instead of Procedures (available since SQL Server 2005)
   or
2. use a temporary table using a Table variable (DECLARE @temp TABLE (...)) which as the same structure than result of the other stored procedure. Then use a INSERT+EXECUTE statement in order to store the result of the other stored procedure into the temporary table.
    INSERT @temp
   EXECUTE OtherStoredProc
   then you have the result of the other stored proc in table @temp

Answer (score -1):

The literal answer to your question is to create a global temporary table, and to populate that table step by step.

For instance:

```
    PROCEDURE [dbo].[vExport_GetClientDetailsBySchemeAndTeam] @startdate DATETIME = null, @enddate DATETIME = NULL, @scheme INT, @teamID INT AS /*returns a list of current client details between two dates */
    create table ##results(//columns you want to return)
insert into ##results (columns)

    SELECT Forename, Surname, Address1, Address2, Town, County, Postcode, [Status], Telephone, EmergencyTelephone --exec vExport_GetClientDetailsBySchemeAndTeam '2010-04-06 12:00:00', '2011-04-06 12:00:00', '3', '152' FROM vClients WHERE vClients.ClientID in (SELECT DISTINCT E.ClientID FROM vEvents E INNER JOIN vClients C on E.ClientID = C.ClientID WHERE E.EventDate between @startdate and @enddate --AND C.Status = 0 AND e.SchemeID=@scheme AND e.TeamID = @teamID)

update results
set (columns from you events table)
from ##results r, 
vEvents e
where e.clientid = r.clientid

select * from ##results
```

However, I think you can also achieve what you want through the gift of the traditional join. Worth seeing if you can join to the events table from your main query...

Comment: global temp tables create a race condition. Don't use them unless you are absolutely sure that no more than a single process will every use them.